# Is it possible to add a class to a custom tinyMCE button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, user-interface, tinymce

I have a a webpage in which i use jQuery UI and tinyMCE in combination.
I have added a custom button with the intention to use this button to drag a draggeble textfield:

[image: image of button]

the code:

```
editor.addButton('drag', {
                text: 'Drag',
                icon: false,
                onclick: function() {
                // somehow add the class '.handle' to the drag button
                }
            });
        }
```

Can i add a class ".handle" to the custom tinyMCE drag button? or is this not posible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `subtype` property to the settings.

That will append a class with the name `mce-[subtype]`.

Refer to this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQBqKE)

Comment: Any idea how to repro in Tinymce 5.0.3?